# open O_CREAT | O_EXCL on NFS in Linux?

Tags: linux, file-io, glibc, nfs

When in the Linux 2.6 kernel and in NFSv3 did `open("fname", O_CREAT|O_EXCL)` became valid?  The current canonical `open(2)` system call documentation (http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/open.2.html) says everything is fine:

```
  - O_EXCL  
   - ...  
      On NFS, O_EXCL is only supported when using NFSv3 or later on kernel  
      2.6 or later.  In NFS environments where O_EXCL support is not  
      provided, programs that rely on it for performing locking tasks will  
      contain a race condition.  Portable programs that want to perform  
      atomic file locking using a lockfile, and need to avoid reliance on NFS  
      support for O_EXCL, can  ...
```

This reads as though all 2.6 kernels are OK, but the man page **[changelog](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/changelog.html#release_2.75)** (ca late kernel 2.6.23) begins indicating validity *four years* after 2.6.0 went live, and the web is rife with boards users censuring this use within the last year or two.  I'd like to use this setup on RHEL 5 (2.6.18) systems, but I couldn't pin down when it truly became safe.  Does anyone have a definitive answer?

Comment: Is there a programming question in there somewhere?

Comment: I intended as much in the first sentence.  Inasmuch as people can ask questions about things like `std::fstream::fstream(char const *, ios_base::openmode)` in the C++ standard library, I hoped that the C standard library was open game, even regarding non-POSIX options.

Comment: The accompanying text has been substantially reduced to aid clarity if that was the original concern.

Comment: The offtopic closes are completely wrong.  How to safely use lockfiles over NFS is *definitely* programming question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently, the NFS guys claim that anything from **NFSv3** and Linux **2.6.5** on is OK.

From http://nfs.sourceforge.net/#faq_d10:

- **D10. I'm trying to use flock()/BSD locks to lock files used on multiple clients, but the files become corrupted. How come?**

  - A. flock()/BSD locks act only locally on Linux NFS clients prior to 2.6.12. Use fcntl()/POSIX locks to ensure that file locks are visible to other clients.
  - Here are some ways to serialize access to an NFS file.

    - Use the fcntl()/POSIX locking API. This type of locking provides byte-range locking across multiple clients via the NLM protocol, or via NFSv4.
    - Use a separate lockfile, and create hard links to it. See the description in the O_EXCL section of the creat(2) man page.
  - It's worth noting that until early 2.6 kernels, O_EXCL creates were not atomic on Linux NFS clients. Don't use O_EXCL creates and expect atomic behavior among multiple NFS client unless you are running a kernel newer than **2.6.5**.
  - ...