# Linux: append content to a file using several processes and using NFS

Tags: linux, multithreading, file, locking, nfs

I have a problem when appending information to a file, a file is accessed by several machines at the same time, using the NFS file system. I have combined the functionality of the function:

```
open(nameFile.c_str(), O_WRONLY | O_APPEND);
```

from `fcntl.h` (see [description](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?open%202)) , and also the locking of the file when a process tries to use it:

```
size_t filedesc = open(nameFile.c_str(), O_WRONLY | O_APPEND);
   if (filedesc != -1)
   {
    fp = fdopen(filedesc, "a");
   }

   if(fp != NULL)
   {
      //Initialize the flock structure.
      struct flock lock;
      memset (&lock, 0, sizeof(lock));
      lock.l_type = F_WRLCK;

      //Locking file
      fcntl (filedesc, F_SETLKW, &lock);

      //Writing log message
      fputs((sMessage+ string("\n")).c_str(),fp);

      //Unlocking log file
      lock.l_type = F_UNLCK;
      fcntl (filedesc, F_SETLKW, &lock);

      //Close file
      fclose(fp);
   }
```

My problem is:

If the file does not exist, it should be created (as described [here](http://linux.die.net/man/2/open)). However, the file is not created, so the contents to be written inside are lost.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

**Edited:**

For instance:

```
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>


using namespace std;

static void writeToFile()
{
   string nameFile = string("filename.txt");
     FILE *fp=NULL;
     size_t filedesc = open(nameFile.c_str(), O_WRONLY | O_APPEND);
     if (filedesc != -1)
     {
      fp = fdopen(filedesc, "a");
     }else{
        perror("Unable to open file");

     }

     if(fp != NULL)
     {
        //Initialize the flock structure.
        struct flock lock;
        memset (&lock, 0, sizeof(lock));
        lock.l_type = F_WRLCK;

        //Locking file
        fcntl (filedesc, F_SETLKW, &lock);

        //Writing log message
        fputs((string("message")).c_str(),fp);

        //Unlocking log file
        lock.l_type = F_UNLCK;
        fcntl (filedesc, F_SETLKW, &lock);

        //Close file
        fclose(fp);
     }else{
        perror("fdopen failed");
     }
}

int main()
{
   string inputString(" ");

   writeToFile();

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Look at O_CREAT and O_EXCL for your `open` call.

Comment: But creates with O_EXCL are not atomic with NFS [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3406712/open-o-creat-o-excl-on-nfs-in-linux) and [this](http://lwn.net/Articles/251004/)

Comment: Your question stated that if the file does not exist it should be created.  That's not going to happen w/o O_CREAT or `creat()` on any file system.  In that scenario your `open` fails and you continue to error out all the way through so nothing gets written.  (Also `open` return a file descriptor, which is an int.  size_t is an unsigned type.)