# Why do tuples in Python work with reversed but do not have __reversed__?

Tags: python, iterator, tuples, immutability, reverse

In discussion of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449674/how-to-implement-a-persistent-python-list/9449852#9449852) we realized that tuples do not have a `__reversed__` method. My guess was that creating the iterator would require mutating the tuple. And yet tuples play fine with `reversed`. Why can't the approach used for `reversed` be made to work for `__reversed__` as well?

```
>>> foo = range(3)
>>> foo
[0, 1, 2]
>>> list(foo.__reversed__())
[2, 1, 0]
>>> foo
[0, 1, 2]
>>> bar = (0, 1, 2)
>>> list(bar.__reversed__())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute '__reversed__'
>>> reversed(bar)
<reversed object at 0x10603b310>
>>> tuple(reversed(bar))
(2, 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [*spec*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reversed):

**reversed(seq)**

> Return a reverse iterator. seq must be an object which has a
>   **reversed**() method **or supports the sequence protocol (the __len__() method and the __getitem__() method with integer arguments starting at
>   0).**

Comment: And crucially [the section on `__reversed__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__reversed__) says, " Objects that support the sequence protocol should only provide __reversed__() if they can provide an implementation that is more efficient than the one provided by reversed()."

Answer (score -2):

**EDIT:** well, I try to say it again (english is not my native language) - with example.

Some functions - I call them `fun(object)` - can use `object.__func__()` to do the job or they use other functions in `object` if there is no `object.__func__()`

-

For example `str()` - when you use `str(object)` it calls `object.__str__()`, but if there is no `object.__str__()`  then it calls `object.__repr__()`.

So you can use `str()` with object which has no `__str__()` and still get some result.

-

Other example `<` - when you use `a < b` it tries to use `a.__lt__()` but if there is no `a.__lt__()` it tries to use  `a.__gt__()` (and maybe other functions too)

```
class MyClass():

    def __str__(self):
        return "MyClass: __str__"

    def __repr__(self):
        return "MyClass: __repl__"

    #-------------------------

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return True

    def __gt__(self, other):
        return True

    #-------------------------

a = MyClass()
b = MyClass()

print( str(a) )

print( a < b )
```

1. You can remove `__str__` to get different result.
2. You can change `True/False` in `__lt__` and you can see that result is changed.
   Then you can remove `__lt__` and you can change `True/False` in `__gt__` and you see that result is changed again.

Comment: I honestly have no idea what you're trying to say here ... Care to elaborate?