# How to convert ~/. path to absolute path

Tags: python, path, home-directory

I have the following file: `~/.config.txt` which is located in `/root/.config`. In order to avoid hardcoded paths in my `Python` file, how can I always replace (and correctly refer) to a `~/` path as `<home>` in Python?
This way I could replace `~/.config.txt` by `/root/.config` if `/root/` was my home directory?

Comment: `os.path.expanduser` doesn't work for you?

Comment: @JoelCornett I'm guessing the OP didn't know about it, not that it didn't work for them.

Answer (score 23):

You can use [`os.path.expanduser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser) to convert `~` into your home directory:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.expanduser('~/.config.txt')
'/root/.config.txt'
>>>
```

This works on both *nix and Windows systems.