# Best practices for creating files with a given file name but the file name is already taken

Tags: python

I have a program that outputs a file and asks the user to provide a file name. My issue concerns what happens when the user provides a file name that already exists. For example, suppose the user wants their data to be written to `foo.txt` but it already exists. I want to output their data instead to `foo (1).txt`. Is there a Python module that does this for you or is there a better way to do it than what I'm currently doing?

The way I am currently doing this is as shown.

```py
def determine_file_name(name):
    counter = 0
    file_name = '{0}.tex'.format(name)
    while os.path.exists(file_name):
        counter += 1
        file_name = '{0} ({1}).tex'.format(name, counter)
    return file_name
```

Comment: I don't think there is an out of the box way to do this. The way you are doing this is similar to what  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17984809/5028532) questions shows. I don't think there is anything wrong with it.

Comment: For Certain use cases Timestamps will help you out too. But there aren't many of them

Comment: This is also how OS's actually implement that. Keep using your code it's good!!!