# Adding Multiple Columns

Tags: python, pandas

How to add multiple columns from one dataframe to another dataframe i laready figured out to add a single column but not getting multiple columns. I am a newbie

df

```
new['Symbol']= pd.Series(df['Symbol'])
dfnew['Symbol']['Desc']= pd.Series(df['Symbol']['Desc'])
```

Comment: dfnew['Symbol']= pd.Series(df['Symbol']) # worked dfnew['Symbol']['Desc']= pd.Series(df['Symbol']['Desc']) # not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
dfnew['Symbol'],dfnew['Desc']= df['Symbol'],df['Desc']
```

Or [`df.assign()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
dfnew=dfnew.assign(Symbol=df.Symbol,Desc=df.Desc)
```

If needed initialize `dfnew` first as `dfnew=pd.DataFrame()`

Comment: dfnew=dfnew.assign(Symbol=df.Symbol,Desc=df.Desc this worked for me thank you so much.

Comment: can you help with creating a file if exists add with number for Ex:SMA_Outliers.csv SMA_Outliers(1).csv ......

Comment: @Hareesha that is a separate question which will require separate libraries, not pandas. :) I suggest you post a fresh question.

Comment: @Hareesha may be you can check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17984809/how-do-i-create-a-incrementing-filename-in-python