# Only allow 1 instance of a python script

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python: single instance of program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/380870/python-single-instance-of-program)

What is the best way to insure that only 1 copy of a python script is running?   I am having trouble with python zombies.  I tired creating a write lock using `open("lock","w")`,  but python doesn't notify me if the file already has a write lock, it just seems to wait.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
import os
os.open("lock", os.O_CREAT|os.O_EXCL)
```

The documentation for [os.open](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.open) and [its flags](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#open-constants).

Comment: This will create a file named `lock`. This file will not be deleted automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is similar to this one: [What is the best way to open a file for exclusive access in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186202/what-is-the-best-way-to-open-a-file-for-exclusive-access-in-python).  The answers given there should help you with your issue.

(Use the flag combination `portalocker.LOCK_EX!|portalocker.LOCK_NB` to return quickly. If the file is locked by another process, your script should get an exception.)