# Make file, 'Currently being used' in python

Tags: python, windows, linux, macos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best way to open a file for exclusive access in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186202/what-is-the-best-way-to-open-a-file-for-exclusive-access-in-python)

I am creating a paint program. And when the user loads an image, I want that file to be 'protected', so the user can't delete it, rename, ect.. and the message comes up 'file is currently being used by another process'.

Is there a way to do this in python?

Edit:

I would like it to work on Linux, Mac and windows

Comment: The keywords you are looking for are "open for exclusive access". Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/186464/214671).

Comment: Hmm I dont think that would work on a mac

Comment: Why shouldn't it work? On POSIX systems it uses `fcntl` to perform the locking, which works the same way on Linux and Mac OS X.