# Is it possible to pause a python script till file is not in use?

Tags: python, file, wait, pausing-execution

I have a python script which updates some values in a file. This script may be used by more than 1 users, which means that file will be updated by multiple users. But 2 users shouldn't update the file at the same time. If a user is updating the file, the other user should wait for 1st user's script to be completed. Is it possible to check if a file is in use in python? If in use, script should wait, and as soon as it is NOT in use, it should continue and update the file.

Comment: Each script is run in its own process so what you're looking for is Inter-Process Communication (IPC). IPC is dependent on your OS so you might want to add a tag for your OS type and version to the question tag list.

Comment: Maybe take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186202/what-is-the-best-way-to-open-a-file-for-exclusive-access-in-python

Comment: What you describe is essentially a [DBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_management_system). Have you considered something like sqlite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some sort of file locking.

I think [this](http://www.evanfosmark.com/2009/01/cross-platform-file-locking-support-in-python/) gives solution to your problem.

Traditionally this is called a resource sharing problem solved using semaphores, Locking etc.