# Python "with" statement can occur TOCTOU?

Tags: python

Assume that, `file.txt` is closed or deleted during the delay between `open` and `write`. (or it can ?)

Then, this situation can occur [TOCTOU](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/367.html) ?

`with` statement sure that atomic until with block or not?

```
with open("file.txt") as f :
    # ...delayed...
    f.write("something")
```

Comment: `with` blocks aren’t atomic (neither in general nor with files). On Windows, IIRC, you can’t delete a file that’s being written to; elsewhere, unlinking a file doesn’t invalidate handles to it. Either way, there’s no problem with continuing to write. **tl;dr: no**

Comment: @Ryan but there's problem when I read deleted file. right ?

Comment: No. As long as the file is open, it won’t actually be deleted by conventional means.

Comment: Oh, I'm stupid. I just try it. thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Can this occur?**

**Use case 1**: Python itself deletes the file*

**yes** it can happen. I just tested like this:

```
In [1]: with open("file.txt", "w") as f :
   ...:     f.write("Something Old")
   ...:

In [2]: !cat ./file.txt
Something Old
In [3]: import os
   ...: with open("file.txt","w") as f:
   ...:     os.remove("./file.txt")
   ...:     print f.write("Something new")
   ...:
None

In [4]: !cat ./file.txt
cat: ./file.txt: No such file or directory
```

**Use Case 2:** Other than python deletes the file.

Then also, found the behavior to be same.

```
In [1]: !cat ./file.txt
Something Old
In [2]: import os
   ...: import time
   ...:
   ...: with open("file.txt","w") as f:
   ...:     time.sleep(15)
   ...:     print f.write("Something new")
   ...:
None

In [3]: !cat ./file.txt
cat: ./file.txt: No such file or directory
```

**How to avoid it?**

You can use exclusive lock from [fcntl.lockf()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fcntl.html#fcntl.lockf)

Edit: There is one more caveat here. Locking the file may not be straight forward and may be OS dependent like [What is the best way to open a file for exclusive access in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186202/what-is-the-best-way-to-open-a-file-for-exclusive-access-in-python)

Comment: It's pretty interested example. Thank you !