# Run a multiprocessing job with Python 2.7 / Windows

Tags: python, windows, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48580406/1422096), I'd like to run this `multiprocessing` job with Python 2.7 / Windows:

```
def main():
    import itertools as it
    from multiprocessing import Pool

    def dothejob(i, j, k):
        print i, j, k

    the_args = it.product(range(100), range(100), range(100))
    pool = Pool(4)

    def jobWrapper(args): 
        return dothejob(*args)

    res = pool.map(jobWrapper, the_args)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The `main()` and the last two lines are necessary because without them, there's the well known bug:

> This probably means that you are on Windows and you have
>   forgotten to use the proper idiom in the main module:
>
> ```
> if __name__ == '__main__':
>     ....
> ```

But even with that, I get this error:

> File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\test.py", line 14, in main
>      res = pool.map(jobWrapper, the_args)
>    File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 251, in map
>      return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
>    File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 558, in get
>      raise self._value
>   cPickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle : attribute lookup >**builtin**.function failed

**Where is there a `cPickle` involved here and why this error / how to solve it?**

Comment: Probably related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27318290/why-can-i-pass-an-instance-method-to-multiprocessing-process-but-not-a-multipro

Comment: See this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8805244/4256283

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All definitions must be on module scope:

```
import itertools as it
from multiprocessing import Pool, freeze_support

def dothejob(i, j, k):
    print i, j, k

def jobWrapper(args): 
    return dothejob(*args)

def main():
    the_args = it.product(range(100), range(100), range(100))
    pool = Pool(4)
    res = pool.map(jobWrapper, the_args)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support() #you need this in windows
    main()
```

You also need `freeze_support` call in windows