# Running Python on Windows, how can I run multiple scripts that write to the same file?

Tags: python

I'm running one instance of a Python 3.10 script on Windows 10.  I would like to run another instance of the same script; however, at the end of the script it will write to a txt file so I don't want the scripts competing/overwriting what the other has done.

The flow goes like this

```
for i in newlist:
  runFunction()
  completedlist.append(i)
  with open(file.txt) as file:
    for line in completedlist:
      file.write()
```

I have a loop that has a list of items to run through.  For each item it will perform a function, capture the item that was completed, and write the completed list to a txt file.  This has been working just fine for me so i don't want to change the structure of how it runs.

My problem is that I have a long list of work items, and I can't run these in parallel.  I would like to launch a second instance of this script and lock the "file.txt" while its being written to so that neither script overwrites the other.  I would also like the script to not fail if the txt file is locked, and instead wait for it to be unlocked.  Something like this:

```
for i in newlist:
  runFunction()
  completedlist.append(i)
  #Check if file.txt is locked
  #If locked wait X time or wait for file to be unlocked
  #Once file is unlocked proceed with below
  with open(file.txt) as file:
    for line in completedlist:
      file.write()
```

Comment: While I don't necessarily know every nook and cranny of filesystems, I don't think Windows' filesystem works in the manner you seem to want it to. A small SQLite-type database would probably work much better for you. If you need to write it to a text file, you'd use the contents of the DB to do so once your processing is fully complete.

Comment: You could have your writes go to independent files in a folder, then aggregate them when all the "processing" is done.

Comment: Just from a cursory search, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186202/what-is-the-best-way-to-open-a-file-for-exclusive-access-in-python) could potentially be helpful.  I agree that a database is most likely the ideal approach here.

Comment: @esqew That's a good solution I hadn't thought of.  No, I don't need a txt file I just need some repository to hold the information.  I haven't used sqlite, but ive used other rdbms so i imagine it shouldn't be terribly difficult to setup.

Comment: Another approach that I think has not been mentioned here - you could just dump the data to multiple separate files (1 file per script) and then combine them later.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [portalocker](https://github.com/WoLpH/portalocker) to lock the file before writing to it. Porterlocker is platform idependent and works on Windows, Linux, BSD and Unix systems.

**Example:**

```py
def write_to_file(data):
    with open(file_path, 'a') as file:
        portalocker.lock(file, portalocker.LOCK_EX)
        file.write(data + "\n")
        portalocker.unlock(file)
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the answer provided by @clfaster, you can use the filelock library with a slightly cleaner code (in my opinion):

```
from filelock import FileLock
with FileLock("file.txt"):
    with open("file.txt", "a") as file:
        for item in completedlist:
            file.write(f"{item}\n")
```

Another option which may be better for producing more scalable code is having an executor thread writing to a file, and a bunch of separate threads computing the data and signaling the executor thread as "write jobs" to the exclusive file.

This option would require some care though, and by the nature of your question I'm assuming you won't be integrating this into Google's production code anytime soon xD.